# Unable to authenticate Client in test

Tags: python, django, django-tests

Python 3.10.7, Django 4.1.1, Django REST Framework 3.13.1

I am unable to get the **django.test.Client** **login** or **force_login** methods to work in a **django.test.TestCase**-derived test class. I'm referring to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/

My project seems to work when viewing it in a browser. Unauthenticated DRF views appear as expected, and if I log in through the admin site, protected views also appear as expected. A preliminary version of the front end that will consume this API is able to read data and display it with no problem. The local Django unit test environment uses a local SQLite3 install for data. All tests not requiring authentication are currently passing.

This simplified test class reliably displays the problem:

```python
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import Client, TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from eventsadmin.models import Address


class AddressesViewTest(TestCase):
    username = "jrandomuser"
    password = "qwerty123"
    user = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()
    if user:
        print("User exists")
    else:
        user = User.objects.create(username=username)
        print("User created")
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    client = Client()


    def setUp(self):
        if self.client.login(username=self.username, password=self.password):
            print("Login successful")
        else:
            print("Login failed")
        Address.objects.create(name="White House", address1="1600 Pennsylvania Ave", city="Washington", state="DC", postal_code="37188")


    def test_addresses(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse("addresses-list"))
        self.assertContains(response, '"name":"White House"')
```

First, I was surprised that I had to test for the existence of the **User**. Even though the test framework emits messages saying it is creating and destroying the test database for each run, after the test has been run once the creation of the **User** fails with a unique constraint violation on the username. If I don't change the value of **username** the test as written here consistently emits **User exists**. This is the only test currently creating/getting a **User** so I'm sure it's not being created by another test.

The real problem is **setUp**. It consistently emits **Login failed**, and **test_addresses** fails on access permissions (which is correct behavior when access is attempted on that view without authentication). If I set a breakpoint in the last line of **setUp**, at that point **self.client** is an instance of **django.test.Client**, and **self.username** and **self.password** have the expected values as set above.

I tried replacing the call to **login** with `self.client.force_login(self.user)` but in that case when that line is reached Django raises **django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Save with update_fields did not affect any rows.** (the stack trace originates at **venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1001, in _save_table**).

What am I doing wrong? How can I authenticate in this context so I can test views that require authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing a bunch of tests recently and here's how are all of mine create the user **inside** of the setup, like the block below, give that a shot.

```py
class AddressesViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.username = "jrandomuser"
        self.password = "qwerty123"
        user = User.objects.create(username=self.username)
        user.set_password(self.password)
        user.save()

        self.client.login(username=self.username, password=self.password)
        Address.objects.create(name="White House", address1="1600 Pennsylvania Ave", city="Washington", state="DC", postal_code="37188"

    def test_addresses(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse("addresses-list"))
        self.assertContains(response, '"name":"White House"')
```

And actually I don't even login during the setUp because I want to make sure the view has a `@login_required`, so it do it in the test itself:

```py
class AddressesViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.username = "jrandomuser"
        self.password = "qwerty123"
        user = User.objects.create(username=self.username)
        user.set_password(self.password)
        user.save()
        Address.objects.create(name="White House", address1="1600 Pennsylvania Ave", city="Washington", state="DC", postal_code="37188"

    def test_anonymous(self):
        response = testObj.client.get(reverse("addresses-list"))
        testObj.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302, 'address-list @login_required Missing')

    def test_addresses(self):
        self.client.login(username=self.username, password=self.password)
        response = self.client.get(reverse("addresses-list"))
        self.assertContains(response, '"name":"White House"')
```

---

From what I've noticed is that `setUp` is ran per test. So in my last example the user would be created for anonymous, deleted or reverted, created for test_addresses. So having the user outside of that block is probably leading to the user **not** being deleted/reverted which is leading to some funky behavior.
And I know the tests say it removed the db every single time, without the `--keepdb` flag, but I'm starting to doubt that.. cause I've been hitting some weird behavior and it's only after I run the test back-to-back-to-back-to-back.. something is off forsure

Answer (score 0):

A friend with more experience put me onto what seems to be the right track, which is a **setUpTestData** class method, that gets called only once. I would not have thought of this myself because I imagined **classmethod** to be similar to **static** in .NET or Java, but apparently not; I have quite a bit more to learn here.

Mostly all test data creation not specific to a particular test ought to go in **setUpTestData**, also, he says.

This works:

```python
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import Client, TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from eventsadmin.models import Address


class AddressesViewTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = User.objects.create(username="jrandomuser")
        cls.client = Client()
        Address.objects.create(name="White House", address1="1600 Pennsylvania Ave", city="Washington", state="DC", postal_code="37188")

    def setUp(self):
        self.client.force_login(self.user)

    def test_addresses(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse("addresses-list"))
        self.assertContains(response, '"name":"White House"')
```

As @nealium points out, it also makes sense to move the call to **login** or **force_login** into the test if there are any tests where you *don't* want the **Client** to be authenticated.